# Runtime compiler is not loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I am using [this](https://github.com/stangahh/angular-electron-nebular) github repo to build my own application. I have created my own custom module named Users and all the routes are defined perfectly. When i created a component inside the Users Module and run the application, whenever i click on the new component name in the menu it shows me nothing and console windows shows me

> Error: Runtime Compiler is not loaded

I did try to find out why this error is occuring but most of the thread show only the solution if it is occuring in Angular application but there is no solution if the error is occuring with Electron+Angular.
Here is my Code

pages.module.ts

```
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { MiscellaneousModule } from './miscellaneous/miscellaneous.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from '../@theme/theme.module';

const PAGES_COMPONENTS = [
  PagesComponent
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
    HomeModule,
    MiscellaneousModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...PAGES_COMPONENTS
  ],
})
export class PagesModule {
}
```

pages-routing.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './miscellaneous/not-found/not-found.component';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }, 
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./users/users.module')
      .then(m => m.UsersModule),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
  }],
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

pages-menu.ts

```
import { NbMenuItem } from '@nebular/theme';

export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: 'Users',
    icon: 'nb-person',
    link: '/pages/users',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Manage Users',
        link: '/pages/users/usersdata',
      }
    ]
  }
 ];
```

users.module.ts

```
import { AllusersComponent } from './allusers/allusers.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NbCardModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { UsersComponent } from './users.component';
import { UsersRoutingModule } from './users-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    imports : [
        ThemeModule,
        NbCardModule,
        FormsModule, 
        UsersRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AllusersComponent, 
        UsersComponent
    ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

users-routing.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AllusersComponent } from './allusers/allusers.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersComponent } from './users.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '', 
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'usersdata', 
            component: AllusersComponent
        }
    ]
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class UsersRoutingModule { }
```

allusers.component.html

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card main-content"> 
      <nb-card-header>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              Upcoming Classes
            </div>
        </div>
      </nb-card-header>

    <div class="body table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                      <th>Date/Time</th>
                      <th>Course</th>
                      <th>Location</th>
                      <th>Instructor</th>
                      <th>Enrolled</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td class="trim">25/6/2019</td>
                  <td class="trim">Chemistry</td>
                  <td class="trim">Islamabad</td>
                  <td class="trim">Shaharyar</td>
                  <td class="trim">Yes</td>     
                  <td class="trim">
                    <nb-select>

                      <nb-option value="2">Edit</nb-option>
                      <nb-option value="3">Delete</nb-option>
                      <nb-option value="4">View</nb-option>
                    </nb-select>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle waves-effect waves-circle waves-float pull-right"
              (click)="open()" style="float: right;">
              <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

package.json file scripts

```
 "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run postinstall:electron && npx electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postinstall:web": "node postinstall-web",
    "postinstall:electron": "node postinstall",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run ng:serve:web",
    "start:electron": "npm run postinstall:electron && npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve",
    "build": "npm run postinstall:electron && npm run electron:tsc && ng build",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev --aot",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production --aot",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve",
    "ng:serve:web": "npm run postinstall:web && ng serve -o",
    "electron:tsc": "tsc main.ts",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on http-get://localhost:4200/ && npm run electron:tsc && electron . --serve",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && electron .",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --linux",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --windows",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --mac",
    "test": "npm run postinstall:web && ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "npm run postinstall:web && ng e2e",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "now-build": "npm run build:prod"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In pages-routing.module.ts file write like this

```
 {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule'
 }
```